# Compare values in two different pandas columns

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
Fruit   Cost    Quantity    Fruit_Copy
Apple   0.5 6   Watermelon
Orange  0.3 2   Orange
Apple   0.5 8   Apple
Apple   0.5 7   Apple
Banana  0.25    8   Banana
Banana  0.25    7   Banana
Apple   0.5 6   Apple
Apple   0.5 3   Apple
```

I want to write a snippet that, in pandas, compares Fruit and Fruit_Copy and outputs a new column "Match" that indicates if the values in Fruit = Fruit_Copy.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Not exactly, because I want the third column to be in the original dataframe so I can easily isolate rows where matches = false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this would work.

```
df.loc[df['Fruit'] == df['Fruit_Copy'], 'Match'] = 'Yes'
```

Using [numpy.where:](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html)

```
df['Match'] = np.where(df['Fruit'] == df['Fruit_Copy'], 'Yes', 'No')
```

Answer (score 2):

Lets say your dataframe is 'fruits'. Then you can make use of the Pandas Series Equals function [pd.Series.eq](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.eq.html#pandas.Series.eq) as,

```
fruits['Match'] = pd.Series.eq(fruits['Fruit'],fruits['Fruit_Copy'])
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

fruits = pd.DataFrame({'Fruit':['Apple', 'Orange', 'Apple', 'Apple', 'Banana', 'Banana', 'Apple', 'Apple'], 'Cost':[0.5,0.3,0.5,0.5,0.25,0.25,0.5,0.5], 'Quantity':[6,2,8,7,8,7,6,3], 'Fruit_Copy':['Watermelon', 'Orange', 'Apple', 'Apple', 'Banana', 'Banana', 'Apple', 'Apple']})
fruits['Match'] = np.where(fruits['Fruit'] == fruits['Fruit_Copy'], 1, 0)
fruits

    Fruit  Cost  Quantity  Fruit_Copy  Match
0   Apple  0.50         6  Watermelon      0
1  Orange  0.30         2      Orange      1
2   Apple  0.50         8       Apple      1
3   Apple  0.50         7       Apple      1
4  Banana  0.25         8      Banana      1
5  Banana  0.25         7      Banana      1
6   Apple  0.50         6       Apple      1
7   Apple  0.50         3       Apple      1
```