# Comparing rows in pandas dataframe where other columns are common

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following dataframe of athletes competing in races.

```
   pos   country       year    round      event       athlete    Battle
   1      Jamaica      2012    100m      Beijing     BOLT         0
   2      Jamaica      2012    100m      Beijing     BLAKE        0
   4       USA         2012    100m      Beijing     GAY          0
   3       USA         2012    100m      Beijing     JOHN         0
   6      Jamaica      2012    200m      Beijing     BOLT         0
   7      Jamaica      2012    200m      Beijing     BLAKE        0
   3       USA         2012    200m      Beijing      GAY         0
   4       USA         2012    200m      Beijing     JOHN         0
```

I would like to assign values to the 'Battle' column that denotes an athlete got a higher grid spot. Something like this:

```
   pos   country      year    round     event       athlete    Battle
   1      Jamaica     2012     100m      Beijing    BOLT         1
   2       Jamaica     2012    100m      Beijing    BLAKE        0
   4       USA         2012    100m      Beijing    GAY          0
   3       USA         2012    100m      Beijing    JOHN         1
   6       Jamaica     2012    200m      Beijing    BOLT         2
   7       Jamaica      2012   200m      Beijing    BLAKE        0
   3       USA         2012    200m      Beijing    GAY          1
   4       USA         2012    200m      Beijing    JOHN         1
```

Bolt has a better position than Blake in both races so his `battle` value after 2 rounds will be 2 compared to Blake's zero. Gay and John performed better in one of the 2 races, so they have a value of 1 and 1.

How would one compute the `Battle` column in pandas?? I am not sure where to begin. I have looked at other questions which include my own e.g. [Assigning value to pandas dataframe values for unique values in another column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68792110/assigning-value-to-pandas-dataframe-values-for-unique-values-in-another-column) and [Compare values in two different pandas columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60102571/compare-values-in-two-different-pandas-columns) but these comparisons and/or operations span over two columns, whereas my desired result forces me to consider multiple columns `(year, round, event, country)` which must be common, and find unique values in the `athlete` column and compare.

I have tried to isolate athletes by `country` using `df.groupby(['country', 'round', 'pos']).apply(lambda x: x['athlete'])`

```
  country          round    pos      athlete    
   Jamaica         100m      1        BOLT         
                             2        BLAKE   
   USA             100m      4        GAY         
                             3        JOHN     
   Jamaica         200m      6        BOLT         
                             7        BLAKE       
   USA             200m      3        GAY         
                             4        JOHN
```

While this isolates the important info, I am still confused on how to compare their positions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC, you can:

1. `groupby` country and round, and rank the athletes to see how many other athletes they outperformed.
2. `groupby` athlete and sum the ranks.

```
df["rank"] = df.groupby(["country", "round"])["pos"].transform(pd.Series.rank, ascending=False, method="dense")-1
df["Battle"] = df.groupby("athlete")["rank"].transform(sum)

>>> df.drop("rank", axis=1)

   pos  country  year round    event athlete  Battle
0    1  Jamaica  2012  100m  Beijing    BOLT     2.0
1    2  Jamaica  2012  100m  Beijing   BLAKE     0.0
2    4      USA  2012  100m  Beijing     GAY     1.0
3    3      USA  2012  100m  Beijing    JOHN     1.0
4    6  Jamaica  2012  200m  Beijing    BOLT     2.0
5    7  Jamaica  2012  200m  Beijing   BLAKE     0.0
6    3      USA  2012  200m  Beijing     GAY     1.0
7    4      USA  2012  200m  Beijing    JOHN     1.0
​~~~
```